# traverse back through parent database items

Tags: php

I have a situation that's keeping me busy for waaaay longer then it should. I want to build a tree of items from a database table. Consider the following table:

```
| id | name    | parent |
|----|---------|--------|
| 1  | Root    | 0      |
| 2  | Child   | 1      |
| 3  | Child 2 | 2      |
| 4  | Child 3 | 3      |
```

I need a function that recursively traverses back from a given starting point until there is no parent left. What i thought that would work is the following, but it doesn't. The while loop doesn't stop at zero.

```
public function getChildren($parent, $output = array()){
     $folder = [select name, parent from table];
     array_push($output, $folder->name);
     $newParent = $folder->parent;
     while($newParent >= 0){
          self::getChildren($newParent, $output);
     }
}
```

What does work is when i exchange the `while()` loop for an `if()/else()` construction, but then i run into problems with returning an response

```
if($newParent != 0){
     self::getChildren($newParent, $output);
}else{
     return array_reverse($output);
}
```

Because i'm in a class-context i need to return the values after the tree is build, so based on that i assume i need a `while()` loop and return the response after that. But i can't get it working.

Also at first i used `while($newParent <= 0){`, but that also didn't work.

My expected result would be the following:

```
print_r(getChildren(3));

// response:
Array
(
    [0] => Root
    [1] => Child
    [2] => Child 2
    [3] => Child 3
)
```

Comment: _“I have a situation that's keeping me busy for waaaay longer then it should”_ – that can happen, when you re-build the wheel ... Using search keywords such as “nested sets” in combination with PHP/MySQL, there should be plenty of resources available dealing with this.

Comment: `while($newParent >= 0){` If `$newParent` isn't zero (as it will be first time you check having found a child), there's nothing to change it.... each call to the function maintains it's own local variables, so `$newParent` for that initial request will still be >=1 after the recursive call.... if you "passed by reference", then that wouldn't be the case

Comment: @CBroe thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I never would've come up with those terms. Got it working with the help of this article: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the FETCH_LAZY connection setting in PHP PDO. It may be exactly what you're looking for (but prebuilt and lightweight).

[Manual for Fetch Modes](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_LAZY)

[PHP - PDO DB connection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)